# Failed to compile wxWidget 3.0.5, OpenGL libraries not available

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, wxwidgets, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to compile wxWidget on Ubuntu 20.04, but I have run into some errors.

I have installed gtk3 with the following command which was suggested in the documentation:
`sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

Running  `../configure  --with-gtk=3 --with-opengl` gives an error:

```
checking for OpenGL headers... found in /usr/include
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available
```

Is their anything I am missing?

Comment: The 'ole `sudo apt build-dep libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5` not work for some reason?  Or `sudo apt install libgl-dev`?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out, the problem was that I didn't have OpenGL development library installed thanks to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/96087/how-to-install-opengl-glut-libraries.

To fix this, install the following libraries using the command:
`sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`

For more information about what you're installing here it is [OpenGL Development Toolkit](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/freeglut3-dev)